# My Pokemon Puzzle

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, video-games

I had no idea how much information to give for this puzzle, so I decided to start with none! I'll add hints if enough time passes / people are looking for direction.

[image: grid of Pokemon]

Comment: This gives me "Connect Wall" vibes

Comment: @Taco タコス might wanna update the interactive grid you made, a few of the images are broken

Comment: @Quark-epoch unfortunately, those have been broken for a while; it's an issue with the API they're loaded from.

Comment: @Tacoタコス oh, that's a pity, its great nevertheless. :)

Answer (score 7):

Currently identifying every pokemon in the grid for all our puzzling friends who haven't memorized all the names, because there are a *bunch* listed here:

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Blipbug | Azumarill | Dracozolt | Noctowl | Pineco | Abra | Doublade | Mudsdale | Diggersby | Espurr | Shroomish | Vulpix |
| Chimecho | Vibrava | Centiskorch | Ferrothorn | Machop | Obstagoon | Galarian Meowth | Alcremie | Qwilfish | Shedinja | Heatran | Torkoal |
| Gardevoir | Exeggutor | Cresselia | Decidueye | Herdier | Regirock | Lairon | Bibarel | Gogoat | Eevee | Stantler | Sentret |
| Natu | Hoppip | Bulbasaur | Porygon | Joltik | Trash Wormadam | Galarian Rapidash | Morgrem | Spring Deerling | Amoonguss | Dialga | Milotic |
| Galarian Stunfisk | Volcarona | Zweilous | Octillery | Cherrim | Combusken | Comfey | Shuckle | Blacephalon | Alolan Muk | Simisear | Haxorus |
| Mienfoo | Dracovish | Decidueye | Dwebble | Roggenrola | Oddish | Tyrantrum | Audino | Quagsire | Chingling | Yanma | Sylveon |
| Volbeat | Klinklang | Pyroar | Cubone | Nosepass | Graveler | Staravia | Shiftry | Registeel | Crawdaunt | Mareep | Wartortle |
| Spearow | Poochyena | Timburr | Mankey | Glameow | Zoroark | Snorunt | Donphan | Pupitar | Slurpuff | Woobat | Flaaffy |
| Drilbur | Farfetch'd | Marshadow | Relicanth | Floatzel | Weedle | Skarmory | Armaldo | Pidgeot | Nihilego | Raichu | Mimikyu |
| Escavalier | Dugtrio | Durant | Golisopod | Dodrio | Silvally | Misdreavus | Stakataka | Kubfu | Teddiursa | Thievul | Whirlipede |
| Trevenant | Magearna | Meltan | Arcanine | Galarian Weezing | Carbink | Togedemaru | Kabutops | Pumpkaboo | Sandygast | Rhyperior | Dragalge |
| Yungoos | Volcanion | Hitmonchan | Raboot | Tauros | Buneary | Mamoswine | Hariyama | Staryu | Tranquill | Binacle | Infernape |

Potentially useful information about these pokemon could be:

- What type(s) they are
- Whether they are legendary/mythical
- Whether they have a Galarian form
- Whether they have an Alolan form
- What region they originate in
- What game they were introduced in
- What their Pokedex number is
- What their name starts with
- Whether they are a first, second, or third evolution (or something more complicated than that)
- Whether they can Mega Evolve
- Whether they have a special Dynamax form
- Catch rarity
- Egg group

##### Interactive Puzzle

[@Taco タコス](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/51105/taco-%E3%82%BF%E3%82%B3%E3%82%B9) has built an [interactive version of the puzzle](https://codepen.io/tacosontitan/live/VwWRbgX) containing the following information:

- Sprites
- Names (As Given)
- Types
- Pokédex Number
- First letter of the Pokémon's name.

##### Type Legend

[image: Screenshot of the type legend.]

##### Tile

[image: Screenshot of a tile.]

Here is a *current* screenshot with all of this information presented visually (clicking it will open it full size in a new tab or window for improved readability):

[image: Screenshot of the puzzle grid with updated sprites, type information, first letter of the Pokémon's name, and their Pokédex number.]

Additionally, hovering over a tile will provide a tool tip with the Pokemon's puzzle name:

[image: Screenshot of the grid.]

##### Upcoming Features

Along with additional information that's being added in the form of a modal, there are a few features in development currently, feel free to join us in [Taco's StackExchange chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129673/the-taco-truck-) to provide feedback or collaborate. The current list of upcoming features is:

- Type Matching (Highlight tiles with matching types on hover)

This interactive puzzle is still in active development and as such, this post will be updated as new features are added. You can view the source code for the interactive puzzle on [Taco's GitHub](https://github.com/tacoexchange/interactive-pokemon-puzzle).

Comment: Thanks for the big table! Also, you forgot to mention the arguably most important thing about Pokemon:  "What type(s) they are"

Comment: D'oh! Thank you so much!

Comment: No worries. Granted, I only played up to Gen 3 or 4 I think, where the types are the unique thing. Most of the other categorizations you mention I am not familiar with, haha